# ¿Como obtener el usuario de un Post en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo dos modelos, uno es `User` y otro es `Post`

`User` tiene un usuario con id `1`

`Post` tiene dos Posts con un `user_id` de `1` y otro de `3` (El usuario de id 3 no existe)

Mis relaciones:

```
// User.php
public function posts()
{
    return $this
    ->hasMany('App\Post');
}

// Post.php
public function users()
{
    return $this
    ->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Y mis migraciones:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Y

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Hago una consulta para obtener los `Post` de un usuario específico y me anda perfecto, me muestra uno ya que el otro es del usuario numero 3.

Pero cuando intento mostrar el usuario que creó el `Post` no me lo muestra:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $post= App\Post::where('id', 1)->first();
    return response()->json($post->users());
    // return {} nada mas
});
```

No debería mostrarme un JSON con los datos del usuario que creó el Post? No logro obtener el usuario. Ayuda, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma correcta de definir la relación desde Post hacia su usuario en la migración es:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

La forma correcta de obtener el autor entonces es:

```
$author = Post::whereId(1)->with('users')->first();
```

O también podrías hacer:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$author = $post->users;
```

NOTA: la relación debería llamarse user y no users, puesto que solo un usuario está relacionado con cada Post.

Comment: Agradezco un comentario por el voto negativo, supongo que dicha persona que votó así sabe más que yo de Laravel.

Comment: saludos @Shaz, yo no hice el voto pero si tengo una pregunta, da lo mismo hacer esto `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');` que de la forma que lo hizo el OP? o es indistinto?

Comment: @element no lo tomes personal, pero con la reputación que tienes, deberías 1. saberlo y 2. poder determinarlo tú mismo.

Comment: Me sale `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'' at line 1 (SQL: create table `posts` () default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')` 
    cuando agrego   `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');`   en la migración y ejecuto `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed -v`

Comment: Pareciera ser un error mínimo de sintaxis. ¿después de qué línea lo agregaste? ¿qué versión exacta de Laravel usas?

Comment: Nonono, lo siento. Perdona, es que aun estoy en desarrollo y no vi exactamente el error. La migración se hace a la perfección pero no se ejecuta los seedes. Al ejecutarlo me sale ese error de arriba.

Comment: Puede que sea por `$post->user_id = 1;` que lo tengo en el seeder. Eso es el error supongo, como sería para agregar Post que tengan relación con algún usuario?

Comment: Haces una consulta y obtienes dicho usuario. Realmente ese error está fuera del alcance de esta pregunta. Revisa la documentación de Laravel, los valores ingresados en los seeders no deben ser _hard-coded_, preferiblemente.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89530/discussion-between-jonathan-and-shaz).